# Truncating timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle11gr2

Let's suppose I have a timestamp variable:

```
select timestamp '2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00' from dual;
```

Is there any way to "truncate" it to something like

```
'2011-02-24 08:00:00 +06:00'
```

(I've cut minutes and seconds, but left the timezone)

The target oracle version is 11g r2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SQL> select to_timestamp_tz(to_char(timestamp '2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24 TZH:TZM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24 TZH:TZM') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP'2011-02-2408:30:42+06:00','YYYY-MM-DDTZH:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
24.02.2011 8:00:00,000000000 +06:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(timestamp '2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') || ':00:00 '|| TO_CHAR(timestamp '2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00', 'TZH:TZM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
  FROM DUAL
```

[TRUNC](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) supports [timestamps 9.2.0.3+](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=372457), but in my testing on 10g Express Edition this

```
SELECT TRUNC(timestamp '2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00', 'HH')
  FROM DUAL
```

...totally screwed the hours and AM/PM.  Didn't matter for a literal, or if supplied inside of TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ for me.  The documentation for TRUNC(date) for 10gR2 says "The value returned is always of datatype DATE, even if you specify a different datetime datatype for date.".

Answer (score 1):

Your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is probably set to display only the date portion.  This works for me:

```
SELECT 
    to_char( TRUNC(timestamp'2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00', 'HH'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )  
FROM DUAL;
```

Keep in mind that the result returned is a DATE, so you lose any localization info.  You can return a GMT-normalized timestamp by casting the result to a timestamp:

```
SELECT 
    to_char( from_tz( cast( TRUNC(timestamp'2011-02-24 08:30:42 +06:00' at time zone 'GMT', 'HH' ) as timestamp ), 'GMT' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR' )
FROM DUAL;
```

To preserve the timezone info you have to do something pretty convoluted.  It might be easier to use a stored function to perform the conversion at that point.  This works much like the Oracle built-in TRUNC() function:

```
create or replace function trunc_timestamp(
    ts  in timestamp_tz_unconstrained,
    fmt in varchar2 
)
return timestamp_tz_unconstrained
is
    tzone  varchar2(20);
begin
    tzone := extract( timezone_region from ts );
    if tzone = 'UNKNOWN' then
        tzone := to_char( extract( timezone_hour from ts ), 'fm09' ) 
          || ':' 
          || to_char( extract( timezone_minute from ts ), 'fm09' );
    end if;
    return from_tz( cast( TRUNC( ts at time zone tzone, fmt ) as timestamp ), tzone );
end;
/
```

I created a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b473d/8/0) for a demo.

Comment: "This works for me" ---- are you sure http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/21667 ? The result lacks timezone doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed my omission right before you commented.  There's probably a way to preserve the timezone in the timestamp, but I'm guessing that it would be even more convoluted than the second query.

Comment: I'm not sure why you introduced GMT. According to the question the timezone offset should stay as it was

Comment: I added a stored function that should work in most cases.  I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it worked for your test case.  You can use the other format models to truncate at the minute (fmt='MI'), day (fmt='DD'), month (fmt='MM'), year (fmt='YY'), etc.  You can refer to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions255.htm#SQLRF52058 for other format models.

Comment: it's an overkill to create a stored function when it's possible to do in `SELECT` in place

Answer (score -1):

Try `select cast(timestamp as date) from dual`

Comment: Read question once again, **please**